# Laravel later method fires emails randomly

Tags: laravel, email

I am using laravel admin, and I am trying to send emails at a specific time. I pass this datetime data into the first argument of later method

> "date" => Carbon @1576722840 {#543 ▼
>       date: 2019-12-19 02:34:00.0 UTC (+00:00)   }

However, it doesnt work as I expected. it randomly sends emails.

```
    $form->saved(function (Form $form) {

        if ($form->model()->to === '4') {
            $emails = EmailAddress::all();
        } else {
            $emails = EmailAddress::where('user_type', $form->model()->to)->get();
        }
        $data = ['id' => $form->model()->id, 'title' => $form->model()->title, 'from' => $form->model()->from, 'body' => $form->model()->body, 'date' => $form->model()->schedule_date, 'is_html' => $form->model()->is_html];

        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $url = URL::signedRoute('unsubscribe',['email_address_id' => $email->id]);
            Mail::to($email)->later($data['date'],new MagazineMail($data,$url));

        }
    });
    return $form;
}
```

As I understood it, if I want to send a mail at a specific time, I should just pass a datetime into the first argement, so I have no idea why my code does not work.

I made sure my env file is correct and set QUEUE_CONNECTION=database.

Comment: SendEmail::dispatch sends the mail immediately, that method is for sending out a whole queue of emails on a schedule. Mail::to()->later() will do what you need it to as long as you have queueing all setup. So as this reads now it may actually be sending each email twice, immediately on form->save() and then also at the specificed time

Comment: I figured it out, I set my timezone incorrectly.